# BASH apache to seek particular file name

Tags: apache, centos

i want to find every log file named 'justjoe_log', on an apache server. I want to delete them all. how do i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
locate justjoe_log|xargs rm -rf
```

You may want to just do locate first to avoid deleting data unintentionally.

Comment: Yes, locate is *much* faster, but it relies on indexing so it doesn't reflect changes since the last `updatedb` run.

Comment: which is typically run daily or weekly so it isn't often very up to date. nice comment!